# Get the tag value from one JSP to another JSP during file uploading time

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp

My project concept is to upload file to data base. The below code is working fine  but the problem is I can't get the `<select>`  value from one page  to another  it always show `null` value.

How to get the `<select>` element value from one JSP to another JSP during file uploading time?

```html
  <FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="upload_page.jsp" METHOD=POST>
       <center>
       <table border="0" bgcolor=#ccFDDEE>
       <tr><center><td colspan="2" align="center"><B>UPLOAD THE FILE</B>
      <center></td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> </td></tr>
       <tr><td><b>Choose the file To Upload:</b></td><td><INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file"> </td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> </td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send File">            </td></tr>
       <tr>
       <td>
       <select name="t1">
      <option value="mars">Mars</option>
      <option value="moon">Moon</option>
      <option value="sun">Sun</option>
      <option value="earth">Earth</option>
      </select>
      </td>

******** 
<% String s1=request.getParameter("t1"); System.out.println(s1); 
********
```

Comment: add the code where you're trying to access the value.

Comment: <%
String s1=request.getParameter("t1");
System.out.println(s1);%>

Comment: @AdriánLópez i can't post my full code in this forum

Comment: Please learn how to use code formatting (and the shift key).

Comment: guys i can't post full code,so i post my code in another site please refer tis site https://www.facebook.com/groups/Javagroup123/

Answer (score 2):

You're submitting the form in `multipart/form-data` encoding. This is different from default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding which `getParameterXxx()` methods by default use. They would all return `null` on `multipart/form-data` because `multipart/form-data` is by default not supported.

Basically, you need to use the very same API to extract the regular form fields as you're currently using to extract the uploaded file. Usually this is Apache Commons FileUpload, so I'm assuming that you're also using that. You should have somewhere an `if (!fileItem.isFormField())` check to grab the file field. You need to hook on the `else` to grab the normal form field.

Alternatively, if you're already on Servlet 3.0, submit the form to a normal servlet with the `@MultipartConfig` annotation and use `getPart()` method to get the file field and you can continue using `getParameterXxx()` methods to get the normal form field.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using 90's style uppercased HTML tag/attribute names and using the since 1998 deprecated `<center>` element and using discouraged styling attributes of HTML table elements instead of CSS doesn't give me the impression that you're learning HTML based on proper and up to date resources. Ensure that you're doing that. Also, submitting the form to a JSP and using *scriptlets* is [disoucraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) since a decade. Ensure that you're also reading sane JSP resources.

Comment: @BaluC i my using jsp page please some code snippet for printing name value.

Comment: Please click the "See also" link for detailed code snippets. I do not post links for decoration.